# Fill between two curves in pgfplots.

Tags: pgfplots, plot

How to accomplish fill between two curves in `pgfplots`? For example, I have

```
...
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\addplot file {something.dat};
...
```

and I would like to have filling between those curves.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `\pgfplotstablevertcat` command to add the coordinates to your data and then just use the `fill` option when plotting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Load the data
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\data

% Input the coordinates for the fill boundary, sort them from highest to lowest x value
\pgfplotstablesort[sort cmp={float >}]\coordinates{
0 0
1 1
}

% Concatenate the two series
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\filledcurve}{\data}
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\filledcurve}{\coordinates}


\begin{axis}
% Plot the concatenated tables
\addplot[fill=gray!40,draw=none] table {\filledcurve};

% Plot the data and the coordinates for reference
\addplot[blue,mark=*,line width=2pt] table {\data};
\addplot[orange,mark=*,line width=2pt] table {\coordinates};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My datafile "data.dat" looks like this

```
0 2
0.5 -1
1 3
```

Yielding the following output:

[image: Filling the area between two curves using pgfplots]

Answer (score 26):

Version 1.10 of pgfplots has been released just recently, and it comes with a new solution for the problem to fill the area between plots.

Note that the old solution is still possible and still valid; this here is merely an update which might simplify the task. In order to keep the knowledge base of this site up-to-date, I present a solution based on the new `fillbetween` library here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot[name path=A,blue,mark=*,line width=2pt] table {
0 2
0.5 -1
1 3
};
\addplot[name path=B,orange,mark=*,line width=2pt] coordinates  {(0,0) (1,1)};

\addplot[gray!40] fill between[of=A and B];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The solution relies on `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` which activates the syntax `\addplot fill between[of=<first> and <second>]`. The style for the filled region is given in the option list as usual, it is `gray!40`. Note that the `fill between` segment will automatically be drawn on a separate layer, i.e. it is behind the main paths. Note that `fill between` is independent of the sampling density, the input type, and even the plot handler of the two input paths.

Comment: This simpler solution deserves a upvote.