# tikz pgfplots forget plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I'm having problems finding how to use `forget plot` in `tikz`. I need only 2 legendentries like this:
[image]

but get a massive long list of every object in the graph. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14506/pgfplots-prevent-single-plot-from-being-listed-in-legend) post addresses the problem but seems to be different to the way I have my code.

NEW CODE:

```
     \documentclass{amsart}
          \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
         \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
         \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
        \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
        \begingroup
        % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
        % axes):
        \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
        \pgfplotsset{#1}%
    }{%
        % draws the legend:
        \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
        \endgroup
    }%

    % makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
    % axis environment):
    \def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

    %%--------------------------------

    % definition to insert numbers
    \pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
            /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
                \node at (0.125,-0.0225){#1}; % <= changed x value
            },%
        },
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
    every legend to name picture/.style={west}
    }


        \begin{document}
        \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.6,0.8,1}
        \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

        \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[%
        width=4.52083333333333in,
        height=3.565625in,
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0.5, xmax=1.5,
        xtick={1},
        xticklabels={Direct Care,Housekeeping,Mealtimes,Medication Round,Miscellaneous,Personal Care},
        ymin=-2, ymax=5,
        ylabel={Normalised cfu (Y) values},
        legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
        ]
        \addplot [
        color=black,
        dotted
        ]
        table{
        0.825 5
        0.825 2
        };
        ;

        \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid
        ]
        table{
        0.755 5
        0.895 5
        };
        ;

        \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid
        ]
        table{
        0.755 2
        0.895 2
        };
        ;

        \draw[solid, fill=mycolor1, draw=black] (axis cs:0.685, 3) rectangle (axis cs:0.965, 4);
        ;

        \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid,
        line width=1.0pt
        ]
        table{
        0.685 3
        0.965 3
        };
        ;

        \addplot [
        color=blue,
        only marks,
        mark=*,
        mark options={solid,fill=mycolor1,draw=black}
        ]
        table{
        0.825 3.56
        };
        ;

        \addplot [
        color=black,
        dotted
        ]
        table{
        1.175 5
        1.175 -2
        };
        ;

        \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid
        ]
        table{
        1.105 5
        1.245 5
        };
        ;

        \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid
        ]
        table{
        1.105 -2
        1.245 -2
        };


        \draw[solid, fill=mycolor2, draw=black] (axis cs:1.035, 0) rectangle (axis cs:1.315, 3);
        \addlegendentry{6 ACH};

        \addplot [
        color=black,
        solid,
        line width=1.0pt
        ]
        table{
        1.035 2
        1.315 2
        };


        \addplot [
        color=blue,
        only marks,
        mark=*,
        mark options={solid,fill=mycolor2,draw=black}
        ]
        table{
        1.175 1.59
        };


        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{customlegend}[legend cell align=left, %<= to align cells
    legend entries={ % <= in the following there are the entries
     4 ACH,
     6 ACH
    },
    legend style={at={(15,8)},font=\footnotesize}] % <= to define position and font legend
    % the following are the "images" and numbers in the legend
        \addlegendimage{area legend,black,fill=mycolor1}
        \addlegendimage{area legend,black,fill=mycolor2}
    \end{customlegend}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? With your code I only get one entry in the legend.

Comment: I'd like to make the legend look like the picture above. Either artificially by drawing the two blue boxes as nodes or by adding a legendentry. The problem is that I can't find the plot objects that make them. Any thoughts how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example appears to consist of a lot of custom drawing instructions which make up the box plot -- and the actual box (which seems to be relevant for the legend) is a `\draw` statement.

In this case, it appears to be appropriate to use `\addlegendimage` combined with `\addlegendentry` in order to actually draw the legend - and to provide `forget plot` to *every* `\addplot` command:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
  \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
 \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.6,0.8,1}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5, xmax=1.5,
xtick={1},
xticklabels={Direct Care,Housekeeping,Mealtimes,Medication Round,Miscellaneous,Personal Care},
ymin=-2, ymax=5,
ylabel={Normalised cfu (Y) values},
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [
forget plot,
color=black,
dotted
]
table{
0.825 5
0.825 2
};
;

\addplot [
forget plot,
color=black,
solid
]
table{
0.755 5
0.895 5
};
;

\addplot [
forget plot,
color=black,
solid
]
table{
0.755 2
0.895 2
};
;

\draw[solid, fill=mycolor1, draw=black] (axis cs:0.685, 3) rectangle (axis cs:0.965, 4);
\addlegendimage{area legend,fill=mycolor1,draw=black}
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};
;

\addplot [
forget plot,
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
table{
0.685 3
0.965 3
};
;

\addplot [
forget plot,
color=blue,
only marks,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor1,draw=black}
]
table{
0.825 3.56
};
;

\addplot [
forget plot,
color=black,
dotted
]
table{
1.175 5
1.175 -2
};
;

\addplot [
forget plot,
color=black,
solid
]
table{
1.105 5
1.245 5
};
;

\addplot [
forget plot,
color=black,
solid
]
table{
1.105 -2
1.245 -2
};


\draw[solid, fill=mycolor2, draw=black] (axis cs:1.035, 0) rectangle (axis cs:1.315, 3);
\addlegendimage{area legend,fill=mycolor2,draw=black}
\addlegendentry{6 ACH};

\addplot [
forget plot,
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
table{
1.035 2
1.315 2
};


\addplot [
forget plot,
color=blue,
only marks,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor2,draw=black}
]
table{
1.175 1.59
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much! This looks like the best solution. See edit for an alternative method I found, albeit there I need to find individual coordinates for positioning  of the legend box.