# Linear and non-linear functions inside \addplot to get a unique legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have functions which have two intervals, a linear and non-linear.
I want to have these inside the command `\addplot` in **pgfplots**, to get only one legend.
I tried it with them in a separated write, but the legend output recognise each one as different function.

Basically, I have two functions to graph, and the legend have to depict that.

Please, help me.

I wrote in the preamble: `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usepackage{pgfplots}`.

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Espectro de pseudo-aceleraciones}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:5]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={Periodo $T$ (s)},ylabel={$S_a$ ($\times$g)}, xmin=0,xmax=5.5,ymin=0,ymax=2,extra y ticks={.3,1.8}]
\addplot[domain=.6:5.5,color=red,very thick]{.18/\x};
\addplot[domain=0:.6,color=red,very thick]{.3};
\addlegendentry{Espectro Inelástico}
\addlegendentry{}

\addplot[domain=.6:5.5,color=red,very thick,dashed]{1.08/\x};
\addplot[domain=0:.6,color=red,very thick,dashed]{1.8};
\addlegendentry{Espectro Elástico}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `forget plot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Espectro de pseudo-aceleraciones}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:5]
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel={Periodo $T$ (s)},
  ylabel={$S_a$ ($\times$g)}, 
  xmin=0,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=2,
  extra y ticks={.3,1.8}
  ]
  \addplot[domain=.6:5.5,color=red,very thick,forget plot]{.18/\x};
  \addplot[domain=0:.6,color=red,very thick]{.3};
  \addlegendentry{Espectro Inelástico}

  \addplot[domain=.6:5.5,color=red,very thick,dashed]{1.08/\x};
  \addplot[domain=0:.6,color=red,very thick,dashed]{1.8};
  \addlegendentry{Espectro Elástico}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you need the `forget plot` option, as detailed in [pgfplots: prevent single plot from being listed in legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14506/pgfplots-prevent-single-plot-from-being-listed-in-legend)

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:5]
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={Periodo $T$ (s)},ylabel={$S_a$ ($\times$g)}, xmin=0,xmax=5.5,ymin=0,ymax=2,extra y ticks={.3,1.8}]
        \addplot[domain=.6:5.5,color=red,very thick]{.18/\x};
        \addlegendentry{Espectro Inelástico}
        \addplot[domain=0:.6,color=red,very thick,forget plot]{.3};
        \addplot[domain=.6:5.5,color=red,very thick,dashed]{1.08/\x};
        \addplot[domain=0:.6,color=red,very thick,dashed]{1.8};
        \addlegendentry{Espectro Elástico}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```