# Area between graphs of two functions

Tags: pstricks, graphs

This is a follow-up question to [Area between curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21398/area-between-curves/228263#228263).

After one day, i found out how to do it in LaTeX (Miktex):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-0.5)(4,7)
\begin{psclip}{
      \psplot[linestyle=none,algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{-3}{3}{x^2+1}%
       \psline[linestyle=none,algebraic,plotpoints=2000](-1,1)(-1,2)(2,5)(2,1)
  }%
       \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,fillstyle=solid](-1,1)(2,5)
\end{psclip}
   \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2000,yMaxValue=5.6]{-2.3}{2.3}{x^2+1}
    \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{-3.5}{2.5}{x+3}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-.9)(4,6.5)
\uput[-90](3.9,-.2){$x$}
\uput[-135](-.2,6.7){$y$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Area between graphs of two functions]

Strange that the followwing code doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-0.5)(4,7)
\begin{psclip}{
      \psplot[linestyle=none,algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{-1.2}{2.2}{x^2+1}%
       \psplot[linestyle=none,algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{-1.2}{2.2}{x+3}
  }%
       \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,fillstyle=solid](-1,1)(2,5)
\end{psclip}
   \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2000,yMaxValue=5.6%,linecolor=cyan
    ]{-2.3}{2.3}{x^2+1}
    \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{-3.5}{2.5}{x+3}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-.9)(4,6.5)
\uput[-90](3.9,-.2){$x$}
\uput[-135](-.2,6.7){$y$}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

Looks like the problem is with functions like f(x)= ax + b.

Am i correct?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As David said, it would be helpful to know what the question is. When you do edit your question, if you can, please a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I took the liberty of pasting the question from the deleted message you sent before. Just linking is not sufficient.

Comment: I suppose the underlying question is: why replacing the line `\psline[linestyle=none,algebraic,plotpoints=2000](-1,1)(-1,2)(2,5)(2,1)` by `\psplot[linestyle=none,algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{-1.2}{2.2}{x+3}` makes the filling of the area stop working? No idea for my part…

Comment: Yes David, perfect and thank you. I tried another functions and everything worked fine. But for functions like f(x) = ax + b, filling of the area don't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the curves used in the `psclip` inside a `\pscustom`, and make sure the *enclose* a space. To that end I've swapped the start/end points for the linear function `x+3`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-0.5)(4,7)
  \begin{psclip}{
    \pscustom[linestyle=none,algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{
      \psplot{-1.2}{2.2}{x^2+1}%
      \psplot{2.2}{-1.2}{x+3}
    }
  }%
    \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,fillstyle=solid](-1,1)(2,5)
  \end{psclip}
  \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2000,yMaxValue=5.6%,linecolor=cyan
    ]{-2.3}{2.3}{x^2+1}
  \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2000]{-3.5}{2.5}{x+3}
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3.5,-.9)(4,6.5)
  \uput[-90](3.9,-.2){$x$}
  \uput[-135](-.2,6.7){$y$}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Werner. I enjoy this forum and it is helping me to write my Master's thesis about PSTricks and it's usage for courseware production.