# Curve synthesis - Adding two curves to get another one

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, coordinates

Case 1:
Let's say I have a few coordinates (A), (B), (C), (W), (X), (Y), and (Z) (possibily obtained through intersection, rotation, and whatnots).

I draw two **piecewise linear** curves through (A), (B), (C) on one hand and (W), (X), (Y), and (Z) on the other hand.

Case 2:
I have two curves defined by two functions, say f(x) = x + 3 and g(x) = - x + 2.

Case 3:
One of the curves is defined by coordinates and the other by a function

In all these cases, is there a way to "add" both curves to obtain a third one (say h(x) = f(x) + g(x))?

For sake of simplicity, all curves I'm interested in at the moment have the nice property of being **piecewise linear** but feel free to relax this if there is an all encompassing solution.

Example for case 1:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcounter{i}

% Curve 'one' .. is there a way to give it a name? 
% Coordinates saved for further labeling, and so on.
% How to do it smoothly?
\begin{scope}[red] 
  \setcounter{i}{0}%
  \foreach \point in {(0,4),(4,1),(10,6)} {%
    \node[coordinate] (one-\arabic{i}) at \point { };%
    \fill (one-\arabic{i}) circle (0.1);%
    \stepcounter{i}
  }
  \draw (one-0) -- (one-1) -- (one-2);
\end{scope}

% Curve 'two' .. 
% If I don't need to save the coordinates for later use, 
% there must be a better way to draw?
\begin{scope}[green] 
  \setcounter{i}{0}%
  \foreach \point in {(0,1),(3,5),(6,5),(10,2)} {%
    \node[coordinate] (two-\arabic{i}) at \point { };%
    \fill (two-\arabic{i}) circle (0.1);%
    \stepcounter{i}
  }
  \draw (two-0) -- (two-1) -- (two-2) -- (two-3);
\end{scope}

%%% What I want is the "sum" of curves one and two ...
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just provided a very simplistic example of what I want to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution using `intersections` and `calc` libraries.

**Method**

1. Draw and name (via `name path`) a first *continuous* path (*x* ranges 0 to 10).
2. Draw and name (via `name path`) a second *continuous* path (*x* ranges 0 to 10).
3. Foreach *x* in 0,...,100 :

   1. Draw and name a vertical line at *x*/10 (*y* ranges y-min to y-max of your paths).
   2. Search intersections (via `name intersections`) between this line and the first path and between this line and the second path (you should find a single intersection for each path).
   3. Calculate the *sum* of y-coordinates (via `let` operation) of these two intersections and create a new coordinate at `(x/10, sum)` named `sum-x`.
4. Draw a line through points `(sum-0)` to `(sum-100)`.

**Result**

[image: some added curves]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
  % a grid
  \draw[help lines] (0,-.5) grid (10,10);
  % x axis
  \draw[-latex,thick] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[right]{$x$};

  % red line
  \def\lineone{(0,4),(4,1),(8,6),(10,6)}
  \foreach \point[count=\c] in \lineone {%
    \coordinate[at=\point] (one-\c);%
    %\fill[red] (one-\c) circle (0.1);%
  }
  \draw[red,name path=one] (one-1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\c}{-- (one-\i)} node[right]{one};

  % blue line
  \def\linetwo{(0,1),(3,5),(4,2),(6,5),(10,2)}
  \foreach \point[count=\c] in \linetwo {%
    \coordinate[at=\point] (two-\c);%
    %\fill[blue] (two-\c) circle (0.1);%
  }
  \draw[blue,name path=two] (two-1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\c}{-- (two-\i)} node[right]{two};

  % one + two
  \foreach \c in {0,...,100} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\c/10}
    \path[name path=line] (\x,0) -- (\x,6);
    \path[name intersections={of=one and line,name=newone}];
    \path[name intersections={of=two and line,name=newtwo}];
    \path let \p1=(newone-1), \p2=(newtwo-1) in 
    (\x1,\y1+\y2) coordinate (sum-\c);
  }
  \draw[red!50!blue]
  (sum-0) \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{-- (sum-\x)} node[right]{one + two};

  % a green function
  \draw[green!50!black,name path=three]
  plot[domain=0:10,samples=100,smooth] (\x,{sin(3*\x r)+2}) node[right]{three};

  % one + three
  \foreach \c in {0,...,100} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\c/10}
    \path[name path=line] (\x,0) -- (\x,6);
    \path[name intersections={of=one and line,name=newone}];
    \path[name intersections={of=three and line,name=newthree}];
    \path let \p1=(newone-1), \p2=(newthree-1) in 
    (\x1,\y1+\y2) coordinate (sum-\c);
  }
  \draw[red!50!green!50!black]
  (sum-0) \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{-- (sum-\x)} node[right]{one + three};

  % a orange function
  \draw[orange,name path=four]
  plot[domain=0:10,samples=100,smooth] (\x,{cos(1*\x r)+4}) node[right]{four};

  % four + three
  \foreach \c in {0,...,100} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\c/10}
    \path[name path=line] (\x,0) -- (\x,6);
    \path[name intersections={of=four and line,name=newfour}];
    \path[name intersections={of=three and line,name=newthree}];
    \path let \p1=(newfour-1), \p2=(newthree-1) in 
    (\x1,\y1+\y2) coordinate (sum-\c);
  }
  \draw[orange!50!green!50!black]
  (sum-0) \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{-- (sum-\x)} node[right]{three + four};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow!! Gorgeous!! Meanwhile, I looked around and saw this [thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/fill-the-area-between-two-curves-calculated-by-pgfplots)  mentioning `stack plots` but it would have been really awkward.  I wish there was some syntactic sugar for 'summing paths'

Comment: Is there a pgf/tikz built-in way to know x/y-min and x/y-max of given plots?