# Syntax for smoothing a coordinate plot with the foreach command

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Currently implementing the solution of 
[Curve synthesis - Adding two curves to get another one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72817/curve-synthesis-adding-two-curves-to-get-another-one).
I would like to smooth out the resulting curve. The present code:

```
% red line
\path[red,name path=one] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (7.5,0) (8,6) (8.5,0) (10,0)};

% function
\path[blue,name path=three]
plot[domain=0:10,samples=100,smooth] (\x,{0.5*rand+2});

% red line + function
\foreach \c in {0,...,100} {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\c/10}
\path[name path=line] (\x,-10) -- (\x,20);
\path[name intersections={of=one and line,name=newone}];
\path[name intersections={of=three and line,name=newthree}];
\path let \p1=(newone-1), \p2=(newthree-1) in 
(\x1,\y1+\y2) coordinate (sum-\c);
}
\draw[blue] (sum-0) \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{ -- (sum-\x)};
```

What `\foreach` syntax should i use instead of:

```
\draw[blue] (sum-0) \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{ -- (sum-\x)};
```

to get the list of coordinates `[...]` in between braces so that i can do:

```
\draw[blue] plot [smooth] coordinates{ [...] };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*EDIT* New answer

You can use `\xdef` to collect the coordinates in to a variable as follows:

```
\def\pts{}
\foreach \x in {0,...,100} { \xdef\pts{\pts (sum-\x)}; }
```

In this way `\pts` ends up holding `(sum-0) (sum-1) ... (sum-100)` which is just right for the `coordinates` argument of `plot`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% red line
\path[draw,red,name path=one] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (7.5,0) (8,6) (8.5,0) (10,0)};
% function
\path[draw,blue,name path=three]
plot[domain=0:10,samples=100,smooth] (\x,{0.5*rand+2});
red line + function
\foreach \c in {0,...,100} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\c/10}
  \path[name path=line] (\x,-1) -- (\x,4);
  \path[name intersections={of=one and line,name=newone}];
  \path[name intersections={of=three and line,name=newthree}];
  \path let \p1=(newone-1), \p2=(newthree-1) in 
  (\x1,\y1+\y2) coordinate (sum-\c);
}
\def\pts{}
\foreach \x in {0,...,100} { \xdef\pts{\pts (sum-\x)}; }
\draw[black] plot[smooth] coordinates {\pts};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that I have change the range on the named path `line` so that diagram does not fill too much more than necessary and stays on page 1.