# Plot a range/subset of coordinates in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

**SOLVED:**
How would you plot  subset of a function in Tikz:

In [Syntax for smoothing a coordinate plot with the foreach command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101141/syntax-for-smoothing-a-coordinate-plot-with-the-foreach-command)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% red line
\path[draw,red,name path=one] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (7.5,0) (8,6) (8.5,0) (10,0)};
% function
\path[draw,blue,name path=three]
plot[domain=0:10,samples=100,smooth] (\x,{0.5*rand+2});
red line + function
\foreach \c in {0,...,100} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\c/10}
  \path[name path=line] (\x,-1) -- (\x,4);
  \path[name intersections={of=one and line,name=newone}];
  \path[name intersections={of=three and line,name=newthree}];
  \path let \p1=(newone-1), \p2=(newthree-1) in 
  (\x1,\y1+\y2) coordinate (sum-\c);
}
\def\pts{}
\foreach \x in {0,...,100} { \xdef\pts{\pts (sum-\x)}; }
\draw[black] plot[smooth] coordinates {\pts};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to plot only the 23 first coordinates of `\pts`

This is not correct but looking for something like:

```
\path[draw,black] plot [smooth] coordinates {\pts(sum-0),...,\pts(sum-23)};
```

**Solution:**

```
\def\ptsa{}
\foreach \a in {0,...,23} {\xdef\ptsa{\ptsa(sum-\a)}; }
\path[draw,green] plot [smooth] coordinates {\ptsa};
```

Produces:[image]

Comment: `\foreach \x in {0,...,23} { \xdef\pts{\pts (sum-\x)}; }` should do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you replace `\foreach \x in {0,...,100} { \xdef\pts{\pts (sum-\x)}; }` by `\foreach \x in {0,...,23} { \xdef\pts{\pts (sum-\x)}; }`, do you not get what you want?

Comment: You both understood the question well. I tried redefining a new set of point as you suggest:
`\def\ptsa{}`
`\foreach \a in {0,...,23} {\xdef\ptsa{\pts(sum-\a)}; };`
`\path[draw,black] plot [smooth] coordinates {\ptsa};`
But for some reason the subplot does not follow the full original plot

Comment: Picture added..

Comment: Use `\def\ptsa{} \foreach \a in {0,...,23} {\xdef\ptsa{\ptsa(sum-\a)}; };...` (Don't reuse `\pts`!)

Comment: Please update your question and explain what the problem is; so far, it remains unclear. Besides, did you mean `\def\ptsa{}
\foreach \a in {0,...,23} {\xdef\ptsa{\ptsa(sum-\a)}; }
\path[draw,black] plot [smooth] coordinates {\ptsa};` instead?

Comment: Problem solved. I guess I don't understand the `\xdef` syntax.
There was indeed an error using `\pts`.