# Fill a region between two sinusoids

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to fill with shade color the region between two sinusoids. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3, every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}]
% Draw axes
\draw[<->,thick] (0,2.5) node[above] (y) {$\rho$} |- (3.5,0) node[right] (x) {$\theta$};
\coordinate (c) at (1.5, 1);
\draw [fill=blue] (0,1) sin (0,1.5) cos (c); 
\draw [fill=blue] (0.3,0) cos(c);
\draw [fill=blue] (c) sin (2.5, 1.5);
\draw [fill=blue] (c) sin (2.5, 0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `stack plots` (see [Fill the area between two curves calculated by pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/fill-the-area-between-two-curves-calculated-by-pgfplots))

Comment: Ah, sorry, bit too quick here: Use pgfplots, and then use `stack plots`

Comment: I can't get this working... That looks quite tricky.

Comment: @bluenot20, can you add to your question if you seek a non-pgfplot solution or not? I am not particularly interested in this question but user @YaroslavNikitenko suggested in an attempted edit that this is not a duplicated or related to pointed answer because this is specific of TikZ and not pgfplots. Besides the fact that he can vote reopen, it is not clear if the intention of the question is to answer without using `pgfplots`.