# How to draw areas between curves of the form $x=f(y)$ and $x=g(y)$?

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I want to shade the region between two curves whose equations are of the form `$x=f(y)$` and `$x=g(y)$`, where `$f(y)\leq g(y)$` for all `$y\in [c,d]$`. I heard that pgfplots can be used. Also, the fillbetween library doesn't load in my Mac. Can you help me with this, guys? I want something like this one:

[image: areas using horizontal strips]

I used GeoGebra to generate the image. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `pgfplots` has `fillbetween` facility!

Comment: Hi. But the fillbetween library doesn't seem to load. I always receive an error message. I also think that it can be used only for shading areas between curves of the form $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$. Thanks for replying quick!

Comment: Have you tried any code? If so, can you please add it to the question? It will be helpful for those who try to help you. :)

Comment: I only use the code generated by GeoGebra. But this time, the code didn't give any output. It simply gave me an error message. And the thing is, I don't know how to plot curves of the form $x=f(y)$. :(

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163654/1952 and read `feellbetween` library section of `pgfplots` documentation.

Comment: Why don't you just use the nice graph you have created with GeoGebra?

Comment: For me, the best way to draw anything is use Ipe. It's free and you can also plot functions. You don't need to know any code and it's like you were using Paint (of course, too much better and clean). Try it :)

Comment: How did you generated this graph in Geogebra ? Can you tell me in brief ?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a suggestion using the `fillbetween` library and `soft clip` to `domain y`:

```
\addplot[thick,name path=P] ({.5*(x-2)^2+.5},{x})node[pos=0.92,above]{x=f(y)};
\addplot[thick,name path=Q]({-.3*(x-2)^2+2},{x})node[pos=0.94,above]{x=g(y)};
\addplot[red!80!black!40] fill between [of=P and Q, soft clip={domain y=\C:\D},reverse=true];
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}% version 1.10 of pgfplots is needed
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\newcommand\C{}
\newcommand\D{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-.5,xmax=3,
      axis lines*=middle,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      height=10cm,
      samples=200,
    ]
    \def\C{1}
    \def\D{3}
    \addplot[thick,name path=P] ({.5*(x-2)^2+.5},{x})node[pos=0.92,above]{x=f(y)};
    \addplot[thick,name path=Q]({-.3*(x-2)^2+2},{x})node[pos=0.94,above]{x=g(y)};
    \addplot[red!80!black!40] fill between [of=P and Q, soft clip={domain y=\C:\D},reverse=true];
    \draw({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,\C})--({rel axis cs:1,1}|-{axis cs:0,\C});
    \draw({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,\D})--({rel axis cs:1,1}|-{axis cs:0,\D});
    \node[above left]at(axis cs:0,\C){c};
    \node[above left]at(axis cs:0,\D){d};
    \node at (axis cs:1.25,2){R};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments! They are overwhelming. In particular, I tried compiling this code in my Mac using TeXshop but I got a lot of error messages and there was no even a single output generated.

Comment: Which version of pgfplots do you have? At least Version 1.10 is needed to run the code above. That's why I added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}`.

Comment: Would you know how to update the pgfplots package? I don't know where to see the current version number. I think the fillbetween library isn't loading. Thanks!

Comment: You can find the number of your version in the log file. If you add `\listfiles` to the preamble of your document a compact list of all loaded files ist printed at the end of the log file. Use the package manager of your TeX distribution to update the package. Version 1.10 of pgfplots is also available on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

Comment: @JohnPatrickStaMaria Or put `\pgfplotsversion` in the body of your document somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I have downloaded the latest version of MacTeX and it's working now. Thank you for your time and help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Here's something to get you started, which uses the `fillbetween` library mentioned in the comments:

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes, localSettings: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}

% graphs
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% arrow style
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

% $x = y^2-4y$, $x = 2y-y^2$

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            axis line style={<->},
            xmin=-5,xmax=5,
            ymin=-4,ymax=8,
            xtick={-4,-2,...,2,4},
            ytick={-2,2,4,6},
            minor xtick={-3,-1,...,3},
            minor ytick={-3,-1,...,7},
            grid=both,
            samples=100,
        ]
        \addplot[name path=A,domain=0:3]({x^2-4*x},{x});
        \addplot[name path=B,domain=0:3,ultra thick] ({2*x-x^2},{x});
        \addplot[fill=blue!50] fill between[of=A and B];
        \addplot[domain=-1:5,samples=50]({x^2-4*x},{x}) node[pos=.85,anchor=south] {$x=f(y)$};
        \addplot[domain=-1.4:3.4,samples=50,ultra thick] ({2*x-x^2},{x}) node[pos=.1,anchor=north] {$x=g(y)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You'll see that I had to plot each curve *twice* - once for the shaded area, and once for the parts of the curves that go beyond the shaded area. You can certainly try plotting each curve just once, but the `fill between` part struggles (perhaps a guru has an improvement).

Here's another version that doesn't use the `fillbetween` library - very much the same idea, but perhaps not quite as nice with the result.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes, localSettings: yes}
\documentclass{standalone}

% graphs
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% arrow style
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

% $x = y^2-4y$, $x = 2y-y^2$

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            axis line style={<->},
            xmin=-5,xmax=5,
            ymin=-4,ymax=8,
            xtick={-4,-2,...,2,4},
            ytick={-2,2,4,6},
            minor xtick={-3,-1,...,3},
            minor ytick={-3,-1,...,7},
            grid=both,
            samples=100,
            axis on top,
        ]
        \addplot[domain=-1:5,samples=50]({x^2-4*x},{x});
        \addplot[domain=-1.4:3.4,samples=50,ultra thick] ({2*x-x^2},{x});
        \addplot[-,fill=red!50,domain=0:3,samples=50]({x^2-4*x},{x});
        \addplot[-,fill=red!50,domain=0:3,samples=50,thick]({2*x-x^2},{x});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think one should fill a region *before* drawing its boundaries. The fill covers part of the boundary curve and makes it look thinner. This is OK when only the boundary of the region is drawn, but it looks weird when the curve continues beyond the region with a larger apparent thickness.