# Filling in Parametric Curve without Using pngplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween, fill

I am trying to fill in the area of two parametric curves like this:

[image]

Here so far is my failed attempt:

[image]

I would ideally like to **not** use `pngplots`. I know that `pngplots` comes with the `fillbetween` library (e.g. use case [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/fill-the-area-between-two-curves-calculated-by-pgfplots)), but I am wondering if there is a way to do this without it. I have been skimming [the `Tikz` documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), but have not been able to find anything. If there isn't a good way to do this without `fillbetween`, so be it.

Here is a MWE used to make the pictures:

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}

\definecolor{axiscol}{HTML}{bebebe} % light gray
\definecolor{fillcol}{HTML}{ffbf00} % amber
\definecolor{arrowcol}{HTML}{cc5500} % orange amber

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain = -2:2, variable = \y, smooth]

    \draw[axiscol, latex-latex] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node[right, axiscol] {\(x\)};
    \draw[axiscol, latex-latex] (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) node[above, axiscol] {\(y\)};

    \draw[color = arrowcol, very thick] plot ({sin(\y r) + 2}, \y) plot ({exp(-0.5*\y) - 1.65}, \y);
    \fill[color = fillcol] plot ({sin(\y r) + 2}, \y) plot ({exp(-0.5*\y) - 1.65}, \y);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second `\path` that basically uses the plots to define a closed shape, so that once you set the right domain, you can use it to fill the area.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}

\definecolor{axiscol}{HTML}{bebebe} % light gray
\definecolor{fillcol}{HTML}{ffbf00} % amber
\definecolor{arrowcol}{HTML}{cc5500} % orange amber

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain = -2:2, variable = \y, smooth]

    \draw[axiscol, latex-latex] (-3.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node[right, axiscol] {\(x\)};
    \draw[axiscol, latex-latex] (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) node[above, axiscol] {\(y\)};

    \path[fill=fillcol] 
        plot [smooth,samples=100,domain=-2:2] ({sin(\y r) + 2}, \y)  -- 
        plot [smooth,samples=100,domain=2:-2] ({exp(-0.5*\y) - 1.65}, \y); 
    \draw[color = arrowcol, very thick] 
        plot ({sin(\y r) + 2}, \y) 
        plot ({exp(-0.5*\y) - 1.65}, \y);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect response, this is exactly what I was looking for :)