# Fill area of curve above a line using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot, pgfplotstable

This question is related to [Fill between two curves in pgfplots.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7914) which started me of.

However, I need to have just the area above the reference line filled.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\data
\pgfplotstablesort[sort cmp={float >}]\coordinates{
0 0.9
33 0.9}

\pgfplotstablevertcat{\filledcurve}{\coordinates}
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\filledcurve}{\data}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\filledcurve}

\begin{axis}[xlabel=Time of day, ylabel=Volume,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left,enlargelimits=true]
\addplot[fill=gray!40,draw=none] table {\filledcurve}; 
\addplot[blue,mark=*,line width=2pt] table {\data};
\addplot[orange,mark=*,line width=2pt] table {\coordinates};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The datafile looks like:

```
0 0.2
1 0.217
2 0.255
3 0.288
6 0.58
7 0.9
8 1.02
```

In the code above I would like that just the area of `\data` above `\coordinates` is filled grey. Does anyone got a hint?

Comment: Welcome to [Tex.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a full [MWE including \documentclass](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). You could try to use the solution you liked to and fill the area between the curve and the line y=<y axis max> and use `draw=none` for that line so it does not get drawn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a macro that generates a new table `\interpolated` that places points on your original data at every intersection with a certain y-value. You call it using `\findintersections{<table macro}{<value>}`.

To plot the area above the line, you would then use `\addplot[fill,gray!20!white,no markers,line width=2pt] table [y=above line] {\interpolated};`, or `...table [y=below line]` for the area below the line.

In order to close the area properly in case your plot stops or begins above the cutoff line, you should add `|- (current plot begin)` at the end of the plot command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
0 0.2
1 0.217
2 0.255
3 0.288
6 0.58
7 0.91
8 1.02
10 1.05
12 0.92
13 0.78
15 0.56
17 1.1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\data

\newcommand\findintersections[2]{
    \def\prevcell{#1}
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{1}\of#2\as\cell{%
        \pgfmathparse{!or(
            and(
                \prevcell>#1,\cell>#1
            ),
            and(
                \prevcell<#1,\cell<#1
            )
        )}

        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{0}\of{\data} \let\xb=\pgfplotsretval
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{1}\of{\data} \let\yb=\pgfplotsretval
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\previousrow{ifthenelse(\pgfplotstablerow>0,\pgfplotstablerow-1,0)}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\previousrow}{0}\of{\data} \let\xa=\pgfplotsretval
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\previousrow}{1}\of{\data} \let\ya=\pgfplotsretval
            \pgfmathsetmacro\newx{
                \xa+(\ya-#1)/(ifthenelse(\yb==\ya,1,\ya-\yb) )*(\xb-\xa)    }

            \edef\test{\noexpand\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,row sep=crcr,header=has colnames]{
                0,1\noexpand\\
                \newx,#1\noexpand\\
            }\noexpand\newrow}
            \test
            \pgfplotstablevertcat\interpolated{\newrow}
        \fi
        \let\prevcell=\cell
    }
    \pgfplotstablevertcat\interpolated{#2}
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort cmp={float <}]\interpolated{\interpolated}
    \pgfplotstableset{
        create on use/above line/.style={
            create col/expr={max(\thisrow{1},#1)}
        },
        create on use/below line/.style={
            create col/expr={min(\thisrow{1},#1)}
        },
    }
}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % For nicer label placement

\findintersections{0.9}{\data}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Time of day,
    ylabel=Volume,
    ytick=\empty,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits=true
    ]
\addplot[fill,gray!20!white,no markers,line width=2pt] table [y=above line] {\interpolated} |- (current plot begin);
\addplot[fill,yellow!20!white,no markers,line width=2pt] table [y=below line] {\interpolated} |- (current plot begin);
\addplot[orange,no markers,line width=2pt,domain=-1:20] {0.9};
\addplot[blue,line width=2pt,mark=*] table  {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great, unless there is a file named `data.dat.tex` in the same directory.  Took my quite some time to figure this out so thought I'd put that info here in case others encounter problems with this.

Comment: Note though that this happens because I used the `filecontents` environment in my example to keep everything in one file. In a real application, the `filecontents` package and environment would not be used.

Comment: Hi Jake! I liked your answer a lot. I'm facing a similar problem as ThijsMuis. The main difference is that he is working with a curve and a constant and I'm working with two curves. Could you check out my question here and see if you can come up with a good solution? I have referenced this post in there already, as I definitely think that your findintersectons command could be a winner once it is set up to work with two curves: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380323/pgfplots-fill-area-between-two-curves

Answer (score 6):

With the recently released pgfplots 1.10 and its `fillbetween` library 
(I learned it from Elke [here](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2322/wie-kann-ich-die-flache-zwischen-graphen-mit-zwei-verschiedenen-farben-fullen)) it's much easier.

- Load the library: `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`
- Give the plots a name: `\addplot[name path=curve,orange, ...`
- Add a fill plot:

  ```
    \addplot fill between[ 
      of = curve and line, 
      split, % calculate segments
      every even segment/.style = {yellow!20!white},
      every odd segment/.style ={gray!20!white}
    ];
  ```

Complete example:

[image: Filled area between curve and line]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
0 0.2
1 0.217
2 0.255
3 0.288
6 0.58
7 0.91
8 1.02
10 1.05
12 0.92
13 0.78
15 0.56
17 1.1
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\data

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Time of day,
    ylabel=Volume,
    ytick=\empty,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits=true
    ]
  \addplot[name path=curve,orange,no markers,line width=2pt,domain=0:17] {0.9};
  \addplot[name path=line,blue,line width=2pt,mark=*] table  {\data};
  \addplot fill between[ 
    of = curve and line, 
    split, % calculate segments
    every even segment/.style = {yellow!20!white},
    every odd segment/.style ={gray!20!white}
  ]; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```