# Filling region between two \draw Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

probably an easy one for people how are used to it. i'd like to fill the area between the two functions with a pattern (stripes, for instance). See the code below. I saw something like this with [domain]-option, but no glue how the scheme works, maybe i'm totaly wrong  :D

JOB:

> fill diff between red and black funktion

Thanks so far

```
\def\dtwData{graphics/data/dtwSimple.txt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Points
\coordinate (x-start) at (0cm, 2cm);
\coordinate (x-end) at (15cm, 2cm);
\begin{scope}[thick]
    \draw[] (0,0) -- (0,6); 
    \draw[] (x-start) -- (x-end);
\end{scope}
\draw[color=red, thick] (0, 1) -- (14, 6);
\draw[color=blue, dashed] (0, 1.75) -- (14, 6.75);
\draw[color=blue, dashed] (0, 0.25) -- (14, 5.25);
%plot
\draw[thick] plot[smooth] file {\dtwData};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Fill the area between two curves calculated by pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17517)

Comment: AFAIK you need to recreate the same paths, i.e. copy the code for the two `\draw` commands. Try `\fill (0,1) -- (14,6) (0,0) plot[smooth] file {\dtwData}`.

Comment: Thanks, the trick @MartinScharrer worked. The ohter thread is informative as well (at)Benedikt, if found right now an ohter variation [fill between two curves in pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7914/fill-between-two-curves-in-pgfplots)

Comment: @Alex: Ok, in this case I posted my comment as an answer. If you accept it the question gets marked as concluded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to recreate the same paths, i.e. copy the code for the two `\draw` commands, and use the resulting path with the `\fill` option. Using `\fill (0,1) -- (14,6) (0,0) plot[smooth] file {\dtwData}` might do it. There are also some option which let you change the rules for filling a path which crosses itself. See the PGF manual for the details.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my finial graphic, FYI

```
\def\dtwData{graphics/data/dtwSimple.txt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \coordinate (x-start) at (0cm, 2cm);
    \coordinate (x-end) at (15cm, 2cm);
    \begin{scope}[]
    \draw[-latex'] (0,0) -- (0,6);  
    \draw[-latex'] (x-start) -- (x-end);
    \draw (13.75,1.7) node[right] {\footnotesize $Zeit$};
    \draw (0,5.75) node[left] {\footnotesize $Wert$};
    \end{scope}
    \fill [color=gray!20, opacity=0.01] (0,0.25) -- (0, 1.75) -- (14, 6.75) -- (14, 5.25) ;
    \draw[color=gray, opacity=0.5] (0, 1.75) -- (14, 6.75);
    \draw[color=gray, opacity=0.5] (0, 0.25) -- (14, 5.25);
    %plot
    \draw[thick] plot[smooth] file {\dtwData};
    \fill[color = gray!60, opacity=0.1] (0,1) -- (14,6) (0,0) plot[smooth] file {\dtwData};
    \fill[pattern color = gray, pattern = north east lines, opacity=0.8] (0,1) -- (14,6) (0,0) plot[smooth] file {\dtwData};
    \draw[color=gray, thick] (0, 1) -- (14, 6);
    \draw[latex'-latex'] (14.15, 5.25) -- (14.15, 6.75);
    \draw (14.2, 6) node[right] {\footnotesize $Grenzen$};
    \draw[-latex'] (4, 5.75) to[out=0,in=90] (6.8, 3.45);
    \draw (3.8, 5.75) node[left, gray] {\footnotesize $Vorlage$};
    \draw[-latex'] (4, 5) to[out=0,in=90] (6, 3.4);
    \draw (3.8, 5) node[left] {\footnotesize $Vergleichsdaten$};
    \draw[-latex'] (11.3, 3) to[out=180,in=-90] (7.7, 3.5);
    \draw (11.5, 3) node[right] {\footnotesize $Differenz$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you set the text labels in math mode? If you want to use italics then `\textit` would be better.

Comment: It is quicker and in the final draw, there will be functions. :D

Comment: @Alex It's also wrong to use `$` for italics, and it looks bad (see `Differenz` in particular).  If all nodes should be in italic, `every node/.style={font=\itshape}`. (And yes, I know answer is two and a half years old.)